# How Can I Keep Blender From Remembering Bad File Paths?

Tags: file-browser

I was installing Diffeomorphic and foolishly installed Dropbox in the process. This somehow convince Blender that dropbox is the location for all my files. I got rid of drop box, but I can't convince Blender to use the file paths on my C: drive, or erase dropbox paths from its lists for importing and exporting, so these operations keep failing.

I uninstalled Blender and reinstalled it, but it preserved its memory of bad paths.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the "Recent Locations" in the Blender File View, there is a button to reset the recent file locations.

[image]

Comment: That's helpful, but not quite what I was after. In the top bar of this window there's an address bar for where Blender will start looking for things. Clearing the 'recent' window lower left doesn't change this, and this is stuck on a non-existent path. Further, if I manually edit the path, it seems unable to find any folders in that location. If I browse through the tree under the 'system' tab upper left, it also ignores all the folders on the desktop, adds 'dropbox' back into the path, and goes into 'not responding' mode if I try to import an object anyway.

Comment: Hm...have you tried reinstalling Blender then?

Comment: There's just plain gotta be a file or path in the User Pref's that's doing that.  Have you looked in your c:\Users --> Application_data folder(s) to see what's in there under "Blender Foundation" or similar?  Your user pref's file is also stored there.  Have you more than one user in your PC?  If so, check them all.  You might also try a file search for 'Blender', 'Config', etc.
Sorry to be a little vague.  I'm not on a Windows machine at present.

Comment: Thanks. I'll explore those places- I just had no idea where to start.

Comment: Um... can't find these folders. Could you please provide a complete path example? 

I uninstalled Blender, searched the whole disk for 'blender' and removed anything that seemed able to hold such data (and a lot more...), reinstalled blender, and it still likes these Dropbox paths. I can't find where these are stored!

Comment: The AppData folder is a hidden folder in Windows by default, so you won't be able to view it just by looking for it without enabling "Show Hidden Files and Folders". You can try opening Windows start menu, search for "Run", open that program, then enter %appdata%

Comment: Current Status:  "Dropbox" is gone from system, but Blender still defaults to file path with dropbox in Import Window. Rest to Default allows to navigate to real file path, but this is forgotten on next opening of window.

I used run -> appdata to navigate to Blender config file. I found three text files, one of which had a 'dropbox' file path in it. I removed this. Blender STILL uses this path as default file path. HOW CAN I STOP THIS?!?!? This is just crazy, and very time consuming.

Comment: Try opening a new file, resetting the file path as you did above, then going to File > Defaults >  Save Startup File

Comment: Well, I used Show Hidden Files and found MORE disguised dropbox locations, fixed them, and now Blender doesn't use them. However, the Import Window now defaults to my documents folder. I tried to set a path and use Save Startup File but this does not have any effect.